# Can "override abstract methods" be substituted with "implement abstract methods" in Java inheritance?

Tags: java, inheritance, abstract-class, overriding, concreteclass

In Java inheritance, can the expression "overriding an abstract method" be used interchangeably with the expression "implementing an abstract method"?

I came across the following question in the book "OCA Java SE 8 Programmer I Study Guide" in Chapter 5, page 296, question #15:

Q: Which of the following is true about a concrete subclass? (Choose all that apply)

- A. A concrete subclass can be declared as abstract.
- B. A concrete subclass must implement all inherited abstract methods.
- C. A concrete subclass must implement all methods defined in an inherited interface.
- D. A concrete subclass cannot be marked as final.
- E. Abstract methods cannot be overridden by a concrete subclass.

My answer was B & E. But the book says, the correct answer is only B. 
My question is specifically about the option E. The book says, option E is incorrect because abstract methods must be overridden by a concrete subclass. My initial thought was abstract methods must be implemented before being overridden by a subclass. So why is option be incorrect?

Comment: It's just a poorly worded question. You have the right idea.

Comment: You're thinking of overriding in terms of changing implementation. If that were the case, as in that's the target definition, there would be no such thing as "*overriding an abstract method*". Did you think it was a trick question?

Comment: I imagine OP is confused by the `@Override` annotation. This is just a handy pointer that the original definition **and / or** implementation of the method signature may be found in a super class.

Answer (score 3):

Let me explain each points one at a time.

**A. A concrete subclass can be declared as abstract.**

Ans: Incorrect.

By the definition, concrete classes are those which `can be instantiated` and this class `can also extends` the base abstract class.

**B. A concrete subclass must implement all inherited abstract methods.**

Ans: Correct

If the methods are marked as `abstracts` in the base class, then the child class extending base class should make sure that all the abstract methods are implemented. `You will otherwise get a compile time error`.

**C. A concrete subclass must implement all methods defined in an inherited interface.**

Ans: Incorrect

this is only the case when the concrete subclass has `directly implemented the interface by this class itself`.

But in this case, base class may have implemented an inherited interface .Hence, its **not mandatory** for concrete sub-class to implement all methods that are there in base class as a result of inheritance from the interface.

**D. A concrete subclass cannot be marked as final.**

Ans: Incorrect

If a subclass is marked as final, then this class can no longer be extended by any other available sub-classes. Marking a class with a `final` keyword is particularly used to achieve Immutability.

With Immutable  classes, We can call accessor methods (e.g. getter methods), copy the objects, or pass the objects around — but no method should allow modifying the state of the object. Examples: String, wrapper classes like Float, Integer.etc.

**E. Abstract methods cannot be overridden by a concrete subclass.**

Ans: Incorrect

By the definition, Abstract methods are methods that are only declared but contains no body or implementation.And since we cannot instantiate abstract class, it is up-to sub classes to provide the implementations for these defined abstract methods.`Hence abstract methods are not optional but mandatorily be overridden by a inheriting subclass`.

Answer (score 1):

An **abstract method** is a method that is **declared**, **but contains no implementation**.

- you can override both abstract and normal methods inside an abstract class.
- only methods declared as `final` cannot be overridden.

Comment: Your last sentence doesn't sound right; you can override existing implementation unless it's marked `final`

Comment: I am regarding this question.why the book says that E is incorrect. please read his question.IT's clear that you cant override a final method.I am talking about abstract methods inside abstract classes.

Comment: they have no implementation. that's why E is incorrect.I meant that normal class's methods can be overridden because they have a previous implementation.

Comment: Why do you feel the need to mention _"without overriding **existing implementation**"_? I feel like that's confusing the issue as you most certainly **can** override any implementations in the abstract class, you just don't have to

Comment: you are right. this can be confusing. I have edited my answer.